# Fetch Blob a Imagenes de ImagePicker - React Native Expo ^32.0.0

Tags: react-native

estoy usando React Native Expo y estoy utilizando ImagePicker para buscar imágenes en la galería de la siguiente manera.

```
await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
```

El resultado es correcto me suele dar esto.

```
file:///Users/agustin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/784397C0-C2E1-4FBC-A8CE-35A3F0079115/data/Containers/Data/Application/0351CF18-7BD5-47A7-BDB8-EB9A209B3437/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540xagustin93%252F5-tenedores/ImagePicker/3C5C8CC7-CD52-4922-90C0-5B148BD0E8CB.png
```

El problema viene cuando hago el fech q esta uri me da simbolos extraños etc etc, dejo capturas de todo abajo.

Función que escoge el picker y luego hace el detch de la imagen uri
[image: Funcion]

Resultado de result.uri
[image: Resultado del ImagePicker]

Resultado al hacer el fetch a la imagen uri
[image: Resultado del Fetch a la uri]

No encuentro por que me da este error.

Desde otra App con Expo en la versión 26 el resultado es el siguiente y es el correcto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esos símbolos extraños simplemente es el contenido de tu imagen que estás imprimiendo por consola, no hay nada de raro en eso. ¿qué es lo que supuestamente deberías recibir? ¿o lo que esperas como respuesta?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el post y te he puesto una imagen de lo que debería recibir, esto es de una APP con expo pero en la versión 26, actualmente estamos en la 32.

Comment: Adjunto el link a un video que realizado solucionando este error. 
https://youtu.be/jy4hFM2hGkM

Comment: Por favor la solución no va en la pregunta sino en la zona de respuestas, además lee [answer], además te adelanto que solo responder con un enlace se considera de baja calidad por lo que deberás explicar y ampliar como resolviste esto

Comment: Vale voy hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

ya he solucionado el problema utilizando XMLHttpRequest, me he generado un método que hace lo mismo que el fetch pero usando XMLHttpRequest, dejo un pequeño ejemplo del método y un video tutorial de como hacerlo.

**Video tutorial:** https://youtu.be/jy4hFM2hGkM

```
uploadImage = uri => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        }
      };

      xhr.open("GET", uri);
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.send();
    });
  };
```